# Mathematical calculation in C

Tags: c

I have started working with C language recently. I have one simple problem

```
 Unsigned int a;
 float b;
  a=8000;
 b=(((((float)a)/65535)-1)/0.245);    //  b= ((a/65535)-1)/0.245;
 printf("value:%f \r\n", b);
```

I don't know what is the problem in the above formula but I am not able to print "b" value. I will get "b value as negative". how to print "b value"?

Comment: What is the result you get and what would you expect to get instead?

Comment: change b to double. and things will be fine

Comment: Of course the result is negative, 8000/65k is smaller than 1.

Comment: In order to get not negative result `a` should be at least 65536, or 65535 for 0.

Comment: @PrototypeStark, `float` is automatically promoted to `double` in that context.

Comment: You are getting what you have asked for. If your formula is wrong, don't blame `printf()` or anything else, just fix the formula.

Comment: Formula is ok, but I am not able to print that value. nothing is printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting just the raw value of b, you would have to do

```
b = fabsf(b);
OR
printf("value:%f \r\n", fabsf(b));
```

Because this b will always be negative for all values of a where a < 65535.0

This is assuming you have a math library included.

Answer (score 1):

```
8000 / 65535         =  0,122072175
0,122072175 - 1      = -0,877927825
-0,877927825 / 0,245 = -3,58337888
```

If `-3,5833` is the value you are getting, then you are getting the correct result.

Comment: I am not able to print that value. nothing is printing.

Comment: @user1759248 What value are you getting?

Comment: @user1759248 You are most likely missing the `%` in the formatting string. Download this version https://gist.github.com/3918045 check the differences.

Comment: Even i have tried in your way it is printing like "((a/65535)-1)/0.245 =  ". but it is printing a value "8000".